# Why do algorithms with runtime of O(n) are said to have asymptotic upper bound, when linear functions don't have asymptotes?

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, algorithm-analysis, asymptotics, upper-bound

When we have only an asymptotic upper bound, we use $O$-notation. For a given function $g(n)$, we denote by $O(g(n))$ (pronounced “big-oh of $g$ of $n$” or sometimes just “oh of $g$ of $n$”) the set of functions

$$O(g(n))= \left\{ f(n):\text{ there exist positive constants }c\text{ and }n_0\text{ such that},\\ 0\leq f(n)\leq cg(n),\text{ for all }n\geq n_0 \right\}$$

This excerpt has been taken from introduction to algorithms 3rd edition. What I fail to understand is that how can algorithms with a linear runtime have an asymptotic upper bound when linear functions don't have asymptotes or is there a loophole in my thinking?

Comment: You are starting from a false premise. Linear functions do have asymptotes. I suspect that you are being misled by a misunderstanding of what asymptote means (modern meaning), possibly due to using the [etymologic meaning of the word *asymptote*](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=asymptote), which is not [its current use](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptote). Although I linked to the wikipedia page for the modern meaning, be careful with that page. It is often edited and 'guarded' by people who add mistakes to it.

Answer (score 1):

The technical meaning of *asymptotic upper bound* is given by the definition of big O. That is, $g(n)$ is an asymptotic upper bound on $f(n)$ if $f(n) = O(g(n))$ according to the definition you wrote.

The term *asymptote* may have other meanings in other circumstances. For example, in analytic geometry, an [asymptote](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptote#:%7E:text=In%20analytic%20geometry%2C%20an%20asymptote,y%20coordinates%20tends%20to%20infinity.) of a function $f(x)$ is either a line $\ell(x)$ such that $\lim_{x\to\infty} [f(x)-\ell(x)] = 0$ (or the same with $x\to-\infty$), or a vertical line at a point $x_0$, i.e., $\lim_{x\to x_0-} f(x) = \infty$ (or $x_0+$, or $-\infty$).

The two definitions are different in several ways:

- The geometric definition (per Wikipedia) uses $f(x) - \ell(x)$, whereas big O uses $f(x)/\ell(x)$.
- The geometric definition asks $f(x)-\ell(x) \to 0$, whereas big O only asks that $f(x)/\ell(x)$ be bounded.
- The geometric definition only allows $\ell(x)$ to be linear, whereas big O allows arbitrary functions (implicitly, eventually positive).

Answer (score 1):

Word "asymptotic" is used to emphasize the condition $\exists n_0\in \mathbb{N}$ $\forall n> n_0$ for inequality $0\leqslant f(n)  \leqslant C g(n)$ and generally does not contain any mention of limit or asymptotic. Even [well known definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) of O big, using $\lim\sup \frac{f}{g}$, have sense only when limit point for O big is not limit point for $g$'s zeros.

As to linear function, for example $f(n)=an+b$, then it easy to find solution for $an+b \leqslant C n $ finding $C>a$ and taking $ n \geqslant n_0= \lfloor \frac{b}{C-a} \rfloor+1 >0$. So we obtain $f(n)=an+b \in O(n)$ i.e. linear function is O-big $n$.